# Jquery json giving error 400

Tags: json

I am trying to get the json feed from my justgiving page.

[here is the code](http://jsfiddle.net/makingthings/j6EhL/) I get an error 400 in the console. However, If I paste

```
https://api.justgiving.com/apikey/v1/fundraising/pages/James-Grubb
```

in to a browser, I succsefully get the feed. Any ideas? Many thanks

Comment: That's XML, not JSON. Note that this URL does not give you JSONP (or JSON, for that matter): https://api.justgiving.com/bd5985e8/v1/fundraising/pages/James-Grubb&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=foobar

Comment: `<EDIT>` - I see Matt has updated the URL already. `</EDIT>` Took a wild guess and appended `format=json` as a query parameter and it returns a `JSON` now -> https://api.justgiving.com/bd5985e8/v1/fundraising/pages/James-Grubb?format=json

Comment: Thanks Matt and Deepak

Comment: ...although I'm not sure how to get the fiddle working, any thoughts?

Comment: click 'here is the code'

Comment: Ah I did not notice the hyperlink at first. Your URL does not separate the query params with a `?`. The callback param name is also incorrect. Consult the [docs](https://api.justgiving.com/docs/usage) when in doubt. Use this -> https://api.justgiving.com/bd5985e8/v1/fundraising/pages/James-Grubb?lang=en-us&format=json&callback=whatever

Comment: Wait a sec. The first path param appears to be an API key. Are you comfortable exposing this to the world !? Please invalidate the key.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28530/discussion-between-james-and-deepak-bala)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your fiddle to this. It extracts the ID as expected.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('https://api.justgiving.com/bd5985e8/v1/fundraising/pages/James-Grubb?lang=en-us&format=json&callback=?', function(res){
    alert('Acitvity ID ' + res.activityId);
    $("#result").text(res.activityId);
});
});
```

Most generated API keys are not meant to be shared, so please investigate if you should invalidate it.